# Xamarin forms: Entire row highlighting when tapped FlowListView item?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, custom-renderer

I have added FlowListView in my project. As mention in the [FAQ](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView/#FAQ) **I am facing the entire row highlighting issue when tapped one item in `windows`**, no such issue in `android`. I have added the  custom renderers like below:

**In Main Project:**

```
using DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;

namespace Mynamespace
{
    public class CustomFlowListView : FlowListView
    {
    }
}
```

**In UWP:**

```
using Listpm;
using Listpm.UWP;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomFlowListView), typeof(CustomListViewRenderer))]

namespace Listpm.UWP
{
    class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (List != null)
                List.SelectionMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewSelectionMode.None;
        }
    }
}
```

**In xaml added `<local:CustomFlowListView>` instead of `<flv:FlowListView>`**.

```
<local:CustomFlowListView
     FlowColumnCount="2" 
     SeparatorVisibility="None" 
     HasUnevenRows="false"
     RowHeight="200"
     FlowItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}">
     <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackLayout
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"> 
              <Image/>
             </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
     </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
  </local:CustomFlowListView>
```

Are there any other changes instead of this for solving this issue?

Comment: `List.SelectionMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewSelectionMode.None;` will disable ListView row highlighting. So what behavior do you want?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT But after adding the above renderer my listview entire row is highlighting when clicking one item.

Comment: Please try to use this line `List.SelectionMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewSelectionMode.Single`.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT No luck, entire row get highlighted when clicking one item.

Comment: Please try to add the line in your render `List.IsItemClickEnabled = false;`.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It's working, please post it as your answer

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT One more doubt, in future I need to set some action when tap one item, `List.IsItemClickEnabled = false;` Is this code affect that?

Comment: I know your mean, It will not effect FlowItemTapped event.

Comment: OK plese post it as your answer

Comment: I have done, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I disable entire row highlighting when tapped?

You also need to add `List.IsItemClickEnabled = false`. And it will not effect `FlowItemTapped` event.
protected override void

```
OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (List != null)
        List.SelectionMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewSelectionMode.None;
        List.IsItemClickEnabled = false;
}
```